# Querying raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, query, raster-calculator

I am using `ArcGIS 10` (includes `spatial` and `geostatistical analyst`).

I have a `raster` (GRID) with a value range of -167 to 18.

I would like to `query` the raster and create a new one with only the values between -117 and -69.

I cannot figure out how to use the `raster calculator` to do this task.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the set null tool in the spatial analyst toolbox to assign any cell values outside your desired range to null values. The result will be a new raster layer with only the cell values you wish to preserve.

The expression you should use will be along the lines of:

```
Value > -117 AND Value < -69
```

and the false raster should be the same as your input raster, to keep values where the expression evaluates as false.

Answer (score 0):

try to use 'reclassify raster' tool from Spatial Analyst
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm

Comment: I do not find the help useful at all unfortunately. I try setting an exclusion range, but do not get the intended results. Not sure what else I can do with this tool.